# Importing RealityKit framework into a project makes older devices crash

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios13, realitykit

I'm importing RealityKit on one specific view controller that only shows to users who have iOS 13 available:

```
import RealityKit
import Combine

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
class ARMainViewController: UIViewController {
```

However, if I install the app into an iOS 12 device (which should be fully supported outside of this one view controller to which they don't have access) it crashes instantaneously with the error:

> Image not found

I tried manually copying the library on Build Phases but couldn't find RealityKit there. My Target iOS version is 12.1

Does anybody have any idea on how to supply functionality with reality kit only for users who do have the appropriate iOS version?

Thanks!

Comment: you can not import Combine in iOS 12, put it in if available

Comment: Can you clarify how to include an if available on an import statement?